# Indexing perl array

Tags: arrays, perl, indexing

I have below code

```perl
@ar1 = ('kaje','beje','ceje','danjo');
$m = 'kajes';
my($next) = grep $_ eq 'kaje',@ar1;
print("Position is $next\n");
print("Next is $ar1[$next+1]\n");
print("Array of c is $ar1[$m+3]\n");
print("Array at m is $ar1[$m]\n");
```

Output seen:

```
Position is kaje
Next is beje
Array of c is danjo
Array at m is kaje
```

I want to understand how this works. Here $next is the matched string and i am able to index on that string for given array. Also $m is not found in the array, yet we get output as first element of array.

Comment: ALWAYS use `use strict; use warnings;`. It would answer you question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ALWAYS use `use strict; use warnings;`. It answers your question.

In one place, you treat the string `kaje` as a number.

In two places, you treat the string `kajes` as a number.

Since these two strings aren't numbers, Perl will use zero and issue a warning.

In other words, `Next is beje` only "works" because `kaje` happens to be at index `0`. I have no idea how why you believe the last two lines work seeing as `kajes` is nowhere in the array.

---

You want

```perl
# Find the index of the element with value `kaje`.
my ($i) = grep $ar1[$_] eq 'kaje', 0..$#ar1;
```